# inst and extdata folders in R Packaging

Tags: r, package

In the documentation, R suggests that raw data files (not Rdata nor Rda) should be placed in `inst/extdata/`

From the first paragraph in: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages

> The data subdirectory is for data files, either to be made available
>   via lazy-loading or for loading using data(). (The choice is made by
>   the ‘LazyData’ field in the DESCRIPTION file: the default is not to do
>   so.) It should not be used for other data files needed by the package,
>   and the convention has grown up to use directory inst/extdata for such
>   files.

So, I have moved all of my raw data into this folder, but when I build and reload the package and then try to access the data in a function with (for example):

```
read.csv(file=paste(path.package("my_package"),"/inst/extdata/my_raw_data.csv",sep="")) 
# .path.package is now path.package in R 3.0+
```

I get the "cannot open file" error.

However, it does look like there is a folder called `/extdata` in the package directory with the files in it (post-build and install). What's happening to the `/inst` folder?

Does everything in the /inst folder get pushed into the `/` of the package?

Comment: All the folders in the /inst folder get their own place in the top directory of the package.  Basically everything in /inst ends up in the top directory so any folders in there end up as their own folders.  But this is just from experience and I can't find anything in R exts that explains that...

Comment: I'll just add that I prefer file.path for creating a path to a file

Comment: you can/should use `system.file` to access files in the inst folder

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You were both very close and essentially had this.  A formal reference from 'Writing R Extensions' is:

> 1.1.3 Package subdirectories
>
> [...]
>
> The contents of the `inst` subdirectory will be copied recursively
>   to the installation directory.  Subdirectories of `inst` should not
>   interfere with those used by R (currently, `R`, `data`, `demo`,
>   `exec`, `libs`, `man`, `help`, `html` and `Meta`, and earlier versions
>   used `latex`, `R-ex`).  The copying of the `inst` happens after `src`
>   is built so its `Makefile` can create files to be installed.  Prior to
>   R 2.12.2, the files were installed on POSIX platforms with the permissions in the package sources, so care should be taken to ensure
>   these are not too restrictive: `R CMD build` will make suitable
>   adjustments.  To exclude files from being installed, one can specify a
>   list of exclude patterns in file `.Rinstignore` in the top-level
>   source directory.  These patterns should be Perl-like regular
>   expressions (see the help for `regexp` in R for the precise details),
>   one per line, to be matched(10) against the file and directory paths,
>   e.g. `doc/.*[.]png$` will exclude all PNG files in `inst/doc` based on
>   the (lower-case) extension.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was going blind trying to search for "inst" in the document.

Answer (score 83):

More useful than using `file.path` would be to use `system.file`. Once your package is installed, you can grab your file like so:

```
fpath <- system.file("extdata", "my_raw_data.csv", package="my_package")
```

`fpath` will now have the absolute path on your HD to the file.

Comment: This is great, but what do you do when you're developing it and don't want the package installed?

Comment: if you use {devtools} `system.file` will be overriden by a similar function that will return what you expect here