# Is it possible to include text files in the 'data' subdirectory of an R package

Tags: r

I have a couple of text files that I want to include for examples in my documentation of data cleaning, however, when I include the text files in my 'data' file, I get an error from `R CMD check` saying that the package "cannot be installed", whereas if I don't include it, the package *can* be installed but it gives me an error saying that it the examples do not work because it can't find the text files (of course). Is there a way around this?

Comment: Try putting the files in an "inst" folder instead.

Comment: Put them in the `inst` folder as I've done here: https://github.com/trinker/reports/tree/master/inst

Comment: can you give us some more information about these "text" files that you're trying to include in your package.

Comment: they are tab-seperated tables of weather data that I am trying to use as an example of data cleaning, @AnandaMahto.

Comment: @TylerRinker can you access them from the examples in your `man` files?

Comment: @user2407894 Yes.  You can use something like: `system.file("extdata/docs", package = "reports")`

Answer (score 10):

Building on @Tyler Rinker's comment, I think the proper place to include miscellaneous files is to include them in a `inst/` directory in the package directory. From Section 5.1 of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf, we get:

> 'inst/' for miscellaneous other stuff.  The contents of this directory are completely copied to
>   the installed version of a package.

This means that you would be able to get the text file using code like the following:

```
readLines(file = paste0(path.package("yourpackage"), "/your_text_file.txt"))
```

Comment: better use `system.file` than `path.package` : This tells more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463103/inst-and-extdata-folders-in-r-packaging