# developing R package with templete .Rmd files findable to package function

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-package

I'm developing an R package, one of my package function is `generate_report()` which generate an html report with rmarkdown using a templete Rmd file and function arguments:

```
#' generate report based on templete file
#' @import rmarkdown
#' @export
generate_report <- function(x, y){
  rmarkdown::render('templete.Rmd', envir = list(x = x, y = y))
}
```

and here is the `inst/templete.Rmd` file: (when the package is compiled, it will be moved to top-level folder of package:

````
---
title: "templete"
output: html_document
---

## Head 1

```{r}
print(x)
```

```{r}
print(y)
```
````

my question is, when the package is `devtools::install()`ed, function `generate_report()` can not find file `templete.Rmd`, how to make the function find this templete.Rmd file in right way ?

Comment: You should use `system.file()` to get the path to the file in your package (otherwise R by default uses the current working directory). See: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938814/package-compilation-and-relative-path/25997946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rmarkdown::render()` call needs to use `system.file` as per http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html

Comment: Also concurrently noted in comment from @MrFlick.

Answer (score 0):

`system.file` is the right way, thanks @MrFlick and @Jonathan Carroll. This is my final code:

```
generate_report <- function(x, y, output_dir){
      file <- system.file("templete.Rmd", package = 'mypackage-name')
      if (missing(output_dir)) {
         output_dir <- getwd()
      }
      rmarkdown::render(file, envir = list(x = x, y = y), output_dir = output_dir)
    }
```