# Including static non-data objects in an R Package?

Tags: r, package

I'm creating an R package that references a static shapefile in one place and two png files. I've looked around for the last two hours to find an answer as to:

1. **Where to store these files**. Do I just create a file called resources and reference that in the function? Because it didn't work when I tried.
2. **How to reference them in the functions I've created**. I'm not sure I fully understand how the package calls external objects and how to go about referencing. For the path, I was typing in "../resources/object.png" and that wasn't working.

This is probably super easy for experienced package creators, but I figured I'd ask because I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Check out hadleys book (http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html). You can put the objects into the `inst` directory. Check out the `system.file` function for referencing the objects. `system.file` is used to find files inside a package after its been installed

Comment: Thank you for this! Tried searching hadley's book, but I didn't know what to look for! Thanks for pointing me there.

Comment: That and http://adv-r.had.co.nz/ are good references. I don't need them bookmarked, both my browser autofill and I remember them.

Comment: @Hanna: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13463722/143305 so maybe we can close this as a duplicate ...