# rcpp package compilation process map to cxxfunction compilation

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wrote an [R package](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfR/) that compiles user-written c++ code with the help of Rcpp and RcppEigen. Every time the user wants to create a new model, he/she must write three files:

- one *header* file for the model class (e.g. [`svol_leverage_bswc.h`](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfR/blob/main/src/svol_leverage_bswc.h)),
- one *source* file for the model class (e.g. [`svol_leverage_bswc.cpp`](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfR/blob/main/src/svol_leverage_bswc.cpp) ),
- a third file with the c++ -> R interface code (e.g. [`svol_leverage_bswc_export.cpp`](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfR/blob/main/src/svol_leverage_bswc_export.cpp)).

Currently, all three files are saved in the `src/` directory, and compilation is triggered by calling `devtools::load_all(".")` After compilation, the functions callable from R are exported to `NAMESPACE`. **Everything compiles just fine in this package framework**.

Unfortunately, though, I think I designed this package incorrectly. I expect the users to change these files frequently, and different users to create different models than other users. So, I would like to save these files outside of the package directory (easy), and to compile user-written code with `cxxfunplus::cxxfunctionplus()` (I stole this idea from RStan's `rstan::stan_model()`). I also wrote [my inline plugin](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfR/blob/main/R/plugin.R) based off of [their inline plugin](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/blob/develop/rstan/rstan/R/plugin.R).

**So how does my package compilation map to cxxfunction compilation?**

My current attempt is below, but I'm pretty sure this is way off. The error I'm getting is

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  file25a041c179ba.cpp:12:10: fatal error: pf/include/pf/bootstrap_filter_with_covariates.h: No such file or directory   12 | #include "pf/include/pf/bootstrap_filter_with_covariates.h" // the boostrap particle filter      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~compilation terminated.make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:177: file25a041c179ba.o] Error 1
```

Stan has a line like [this](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/blob/71ab1409531c2c5e412635482fee545c77e2a070/rstan/rstan/R/plugin.R#L41-L43) in their plugin that finds all their header files (e.g. `system.file("include", "stan", "math", "prim", package = "StanHeaders", mustWork = TRUE)`). However, my package's header files don't appear to be installed anywhere in that same directory. Why don't my headers get installed?

```
src <- r"(// replace every instance of <TODO> with your own code! 

#include "svol_leverage_bswc.h" 

Svol_leverageBSWC::Svol_leverageBSWC(double phi, double mu, double sigma, double rho)
{
  m_params << phi, mu, sigma, rho;
}


auto Svol_leverageBSWC::q1Samp(const ovec &y1, const cvec& z1) -> svec
{
  // phi, mu, sigma, rho
  svec x1samp;
  x1samp(0) = m_example_stdNormSampler.sample() * m_params(2) / std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(0) * m_params(0));
  return x1samp;
}


auto Svol_leverageBSWC::fSamp(const svec &xtm1, const cvec& zt) -> svec
{
  // phi, mu, sigma, rho
  svec xt;
  double mean = m_params(1) + m_params(0) * (xtm1(0) - m_params(1)) +
    zt(0) * m_params(3) * m_params(2) * std::exp(-.5 * xtm1(0));
  xt(0) = mean + m_example_stdNormSampler.sample() * m_params(2) * std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(3) * m_params(3));
  return xt;
}


double Svol_leverageBSWC::logGEv(const ovec &yt, const svec &xt, const cvec& zt)
{
  return rveval::evalUnivNorm<double>(
    yt(0),
    0.0,
    std::exp(.5 * xt(0)),
    true);
}



double Svol_leverageBSWC::logMuEv(const svec &x1, const cvec& z1)
{
  // parameter order phi, mu, sigma, rho
  return rveval::evalUnivNorm<double>(
    x1(0),
    0.0,
    m_params(2) / std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(0) * m_params(0)),
    true);
}


double Svol_leverageBSWC::logQ1Ev(const svec &x1, const ovec &y1, const cvec& z1)
{
  // parameter order phi, mu, sigma, rho
  return rveval::evalUnivNorm<double>(
    x1(0),
    0.0,
    m_params(2) / std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(0) * m_params(0)),
    true);  
}
)"

header <- r"(// replace every instance of <TODO> with your own code! 

#ifndef SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC_H
#define SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC_H

#include "pf/include/pf/bootstrap_filter_with_covariates.h" // the boostrap particle filter
#include "pf/include/pf/rv_samp.h"                              // for sampling random numbers
#include "pf/include/pf/rv_eval.h"                              // for evaluating densities and pmfs
#include "pf/include/pf/resamplers.h"                         // for resampling classes

using namespace pf;
using namespace pf::filters;
using namespace pf::resamplers;

#define nparts_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 500    // number of particles
#define dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 1  // dimension of state vectors
#define dimobs_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 1    // dimension of observation vectors
#define dimcov_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 1    // dimension of covariate vectors
#define dimparam_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 4  // dimension of parameters

// helper type aliases
using resampT   = mn_resamp_fast1<nparts_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,double>;
using svec      = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using ovec      = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimobs_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using cvec      = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimcov_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using param_vec = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimparam_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using DynMat    = Eigen::Matrix  <double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
using func      = std::function  <const DynMat(const svec&, const cvec&)>;
using BasePF    = BSFilterWC     <nparts_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, dimobs_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, dimcov_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, resampT, double, true>;


/**
 * @brief a particle filter class template for a TODO model
 *
 */
class Svol_leverageBSWC : public BasePF
{
private:

  // example parameter
  param_vec m_params;

  // use this for sampling
  rvsamp::UnivNormSampler<double> m_example_stdNormSampler; 
  
  // required by algorithm and required to define your model
  double logQ1Ev (const svec &x1,   const ovec &y1,  const cvec &z1 );
  double logMuEv (const svec &x1,   const cvec &z1                  );
  double logGEv  (const ovec &yt,   const svec &xt,  const cvec& zt );
  auto   q1Samp  (const ovec &y1,   const cvec& z1                  ) -> svec;
  auto   fSamp   (const svec &xtm1, const cvec &zt                  ) -> svec;
  
public:

  // constructor
  Svol_leverageBSWC(double phi, double mu, double sigma, double rho);
  
};

#endif  // SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC_H)"

#   //' @useDynLib pfr, .registration = TRUE
# //' @import RcppEigen
#   //' @importFrom Rcpp evalCpp
# //' @export
#   // [[Rcpp::export]]
#   double svol_leverage_bswc_approx_LL(const Rcpp::NumericVector& obsTS, const Rcpp::NumericVector& params){
#     
    
body <- r"(
  // instantiate model with arg params
  Svol_leverageBSWC mod(params[0],params[1],params[2],params[3]);

  // calculate likelihood by iterating through time series
  double ans(0.0);
  ovec yt, ytm1;
  for (int i = 1; i < obsTS.length(); i++){
    yt << obsTS[i]; ytm1 << obsTS[i-1];
    mod.filter(yt, ytm1);
    ans += mod.getLogCondLike();
  }
  return ans;
)"



#inline::registerPlugin("pfr", pfrplugin)
thisMod <- cxxfunplus::cxxfunctionplus(signature(), body = body, plugin = "pfr", includes = header, verbose = T)
```

Comment: See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463103/inst-and-extdata-folders-in-r-packaging/13463722#13463722 -- for headers to be installed they MUST be in inst/include which becomes include in the installed package.  See any header-providing package on CRAN for examples.  As for rest, it all seems a wee bit specific to your package but you should be able to look at what `sourceCpp()` and of course `(r)stan` do and build something for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [Rcpp modules vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) and jamming it all in `includes=` works:

```
inc <- r"(
#ifndef SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC_H
#define SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC_H

#include "pf/bootstrap_filter_with_covariates.h" // the boostrap particle filter
#include "pf/rv_samp.h"                                 // for sampling random numbers
#include "pf/rv_eval.h"                                 // for evaluating densities and pmfs
#include "pf/resamplers.h"                        // for resampling classes

using namespace pf;
using namespace pf::filters;
using namespace pf::resamplers;

#define nparts_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 500    // number of particles
#define dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 1  // dimension of state vectors
#define dimobs_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 1    // dimension of observation vectors
#define dimcov_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 1    // dimension of covariate vectors
#define dimparam_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC 4  // dimension of parameters

// helper type aliases
using resampT   = mn_resamp_fast1<nparts_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,double>;
using svec      = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using ovec      = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimobs_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using cvec      = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimcov_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using param_vec = Eigen::Matrix  <double, dimparam_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC,1>;
using DynMat    = Eigen::Matrix  <double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
using func      = std::function  <const DynMat(const svec&, const cvec&)>;
using BasePF    = BSFilterWC     <nparts_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, dimstate_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, dimobs_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, dimcov_SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC, resampT, double, true>;


/**
 * @brief a particle filter class template for a TODO model
 *
 */
class Svol_leverageBSWC : public BasePF
{
private:

  // example parameter
  param_vec m_params;

  // use this for sampling
  rvsamp::UnivNormSampler<double> m_example_stdNormSampler; 
  
  // required by algorithm and required to define your model
  double logQ1Ev (const svec &x1,   const ovec &y1,  const cvec &z1 );
  double logMuEv (const svec &x1,   const cvec &z1                  );
  double logGEv  (const ovec &yt,   const svec &xt,  const cvec& zt );
  auto   q1Samp  (const ovec &y1,   const cvec& z1                  ) -> svec;
  auto   fSamp   (const svec &xtm1, const cvec &zt                  ) -> svec;
  
public:

  // constructor
  Svol_leverageBSWC(double phi, double mu, double sigma, double rho);
  
};

#endif  // SVOL_LEVERAGE_BSWC_H
  
  
double svol_leverage_bswc_approx_LL(const Rcpp::NumericVector& obsTS, const Rcpp::NumericVector& params){

    // instantiate model with arg params
  Svol_leverageBSWC mod(params[0],params[1],params[2],params[3]);

  // calculate likelihood by iterating through time series
  double ans(0.0);
  ovec yt, ytm1;
  for (int i = 1; i < obsTS.length(); i++){
    yt << obsTS[i]; ytm1 << obsTS[i-1];
    mod.filter(yt, ytm1);
    ans += mod.getLogCondLike();
  }
  return ans;
  
}

Svol_leverageBSWC::Svol_leverageBSWC(double phi, double mu, double sigma, double rho)
{
  m_params << phi, mu, sigma, rho;
}


auto Svol_leverageBSWC::q1Samp(const ovec &y1, const cvec& z1) -> svec
{
  // phi, mu, sigma, rho
  svec x1samp;
  x1samp(0) = m_example_stdNormSampler.sample() * m_params(2) / std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(0) * m_params(0));
  return x1samp;
}


auto Svol_leverageBSWC::fSamp(const svec &xtm1, const cvec& zt) -> svec
{
  // phi, mu, sigma, rho
  svec xt;
  double mean = m_params(1) + m_params(0) * (xtm1(0) - m_params(1)) +
    zt(0) * m_params(3) * m_params(2) * std::exp(-.5 * xtm1(0));
  xt(0) = mean + m_example_stdNormSampler.sample() * m_params(2) * std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(3) * m_params(3));
  return xt;
}


double Svol_leverageBSWC::logGEv(const ovec &yt, const svec &xt, const cvec& zt)
{
  return rveval::evalUnivNorm<double>(
    yt(0),
    0.0,
    std::exp(.5 * xt(0)),
    true);
}


double Svol_leverageBSWC::logMuEv(const svec &x1, const cvec& z1)
{
  // parameter order phi, mu, sigma, rho
  return rveval::evalUnivNorm<double>(
    x1(0),
    0.0,
    m_params(2) / std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(0) * m_params(0)),
    true);
}


double Svol_leverageBSWC::logQ1Ev(const svec &x1, const ovec &y1, const cvec& z1)
{
  // parameter order phi, mu, sigma, rho
  return rveval::evalUnivNorm<double>(
    x1(0),
    0.0,
    m_params(2) / std::sqrt(1.0 - m_params(0) * m_params(0)),
    true);  
}



)"

inline::registerPlugin("pfr", pfrplugin)
yay <- cxxfunplus::cxxfunctionplus(signature(), plugin = "pfr", includes = inc)
```